# Converting code from Stata to R

Tags: r, stata

How can I convert the following code from Stata to R?

```
gen a01sb=cond(b01~=1 & c01~=1, a01, 0)
```

I know that it is sorted by and includes an if-else-condition but I don't know how to code this in R.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a guess (and I don't know what `~=` means so am assuming "not equals" is the meaning):  `a01sb <- ifelse(b01 !=1 & c01 !=1, a01, 0)`. (There would be no sorting. Sorting would not make a great deal of sense if trying to keep results associated with the vectors on which the calculations are made.)

Comment: a01sb <- ifelse(b01 == 1 & c01 == 1, a01, 0)

Comment: @Mislav: You should check the Stata documentation.

Comment: @42 is right. `~=` means not equal in Stata (and, in my experience, is far less commonly used in Stata than `!=`). Also, this Stata code by itself does no sorting and is not dependent on a previous sort.

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought it means ==

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Stata both `!=` and `~=` mean "not equals" but in R only `!=` would be equivalent. The `ifelse` function usually is done within a dataframe but can also work with vectorized logical operators such as `&` used in the first argument

```
a01sb <- ifelse( (b01 != 1)& (c01 != 1), a01, 0) # inner parens used for clarity
```

(There would be no sorting. Sorting would not make a great deal of sense if trying to keep results associated with the vectors on which the calculations are made.)